# I want to reuse Kendo Window that includes an ajax form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, ajax.beginform

I have a Kendo UI Window that includes an ajax form.  The problem I´m facing is that after a successful POST, and I close the window, I reopen the window to reuse it but next time I submit the form it will POST twice, and so on.  If I submit for the third time it will POST three times etc.

I have already tried using the destroy() function, to completely remove the window from the DOM, and then rebuild it via jQuery, but with same effect.  I have also tried emptying the content of the window prior to loading it with markup code.

I have been reading the [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/window/overview#using-kendo-ui-window-with-a-form) from Telerik and they suggest putting the UpdateTargetId outside of the form, I´ve also tried that with same effect.  I know there is something missing and I can´t pinpoint it.

How should I proceed in using Kendo Window with form as a reusable Window (without posting the same number as I use the window)?

**My ajax form inside the window:**

```
//abbreviated
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")"></script>
//abbreviated
<div id="paymentFormId">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("action", "controller", new { id = id }, new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            UpdateTargetId = "paymentFormId",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            LoadingElementId = "loader"
        }, new { id = "payment-form" }))
    {
        @Html.Partial("PaymentForm", new PaymentForm())
    }
</div>
//abbreviated
```

**My PaymentForm markup:**

```
//abbreviated
//bunch of text fields to submit
//abbreviated
<button type="submit" class="k-button">Submit</button>
<button onclick="closeWindow()" class="k-button">Close</button>
```

**My Window declaration:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("Window")
    .Title("My Win")
    .Content("Loading info...")
    .Modal(true)
    .Draggable()
    .Visible(false)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "padding: 10px 15px; max-width: 400px;" })
    .AutoFocus(true)
    .Position(p => p.Top(100).Left(400))
    .Events(e => e.Close("onWindowClose"))
)
```

**Some scripts:**

```
//This script is the one that triggers the window to open
function openWindow(id) {
    var window = $("#Window").data("kendoWindow");
    window.refresh({
        url: "/controller/action",
        data: {
            id: id
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, exceptionThrown) {
            window.close();
            alert($.parseJSON(xhr.responseText));
        }
    });
    window.open();
}

//This is the registered close event
function onWindowClose(e) {
    var id = $("#ID").val();
    if (id != null) {
        $.ajax("/controller/action", {
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                id: id
            },
            success: function (data) {
                //TODO: derp
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, exceptionThrown) {
                alert($.parseJSON(xhr.responseText));
            }
        });
    }
    //var myWin = new $("#Window").data("kendoWindow");
    //myWin.destroy();
    $(this.element).empty();
    $(this.element).html("Loading content...");
}
```

Comment: I found out the problem.  I remove the unobtrusive script inclusion from the window to the masterpage header, therefore the script was only included once.  I didn´t notice the each time I used the window, the script was included aswell.  After excluding it from the window everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have a kendo window that I reuse that contains a form element, which in turn contains some text input boxes and a file input box.  In order to keep that form from resubmitting the file inputs, I reset the form on kendo window close.  I had to do it off of the main thread to keep from borking up the POST that was happening by calling something like

```
closeAddAttachmentWindow: function () {
        var window = $("#addAttachmentWindow").data("kendoWindow");
        window.close();

        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#formUpload").trigger('reset');
        }, 200);
    },
```

Have you tried something like that in your OnWindowClose(e) function ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @RobinGiltner.  I tried your answer but still it wouldn´t work.  The trigger is for the form-id isn´t it?  As in my case it would be like this $("#payment-form").trigger('reset');

Comment: Yeah, that is what I used.  Oh well, maybe someone will have a better idea.

Comment: Hello again @RobinGlitner, I found out the problem, I will explain in my post.  However I will up you for your answer because resetting the form is a good idead  :)